# Does Intellij Ultimate 12 support Python/Django?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I tried installing the Python plugin, but it just [doesn't seem to work](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5479044?tstart=0) under IntelliJ 12.1.6.

Has Jetbrains abandoned the plugin in favor of PyCharms?

Comment: Can you confirm the version of the Python plugin?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I tried versions 1216 and 1294 - the two latest versions of the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried installing the Python plugin, but it just doesn't seem to work under IntelliJ 12.1.6.

Out of curiosity, you say it does not work in 12.1.6, but you link to a forum post from 14 Feb 2013, [the day 12.0.4 was the released](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/02/intellij-idea-1204-update-is-available/). So I'm not sure how that's relevant.

> Has Jetbrains abandoned the plugin in favor of PyCharms?

The PHP plug-in is basically PyCharm's code bundled for IntelliJ IDEA. I highly doubt JetBrains is abandoning the plug-in. IntelliJ IDEA is its flagship polyglot IDE. And given they released a new version of it less then 2 weeks ago, that's a pretty good sign it is not abandoned.

I'm a little confused as to what versions of the Python plug-in you have tried. You indicate in your above comment "versions 1216 and 1294". I'm not seeing how those values map the the plug-in version. The latest version of the [Python plug-in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=631) is v3.0.1 which is for IDEA 13 (currently in EAP/beta). The latest plug-in for IDEA 12 (build 129-*) is v2.10.2 released 2013-08-26.

If you are manually downloading the plug-in, you need to pay attention to the "Since build" and "Until build" values.  (If you only upgrade from within the Plug-in Manager within IDEA< this is all managed for you.) IDEA 12.1.x builds are on the 129.* branch. IDEA 12.0.x was the 123.* branch. And IDEA 13 is the 133.* branch (with some early releases on the 130.* and 131.* branches).  So for 12.1.x, the *only* compatible plug-ins are:

- [v2.10.2](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=idea&updateId=13991)
- [v2.10.1](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=idea&updateId=12812)

All others are either for earlier versions of IDEA or for the upcoming IDEA 13. IDEA v12.1.6 with Python Plug-in v2.10.2 works fine for me.

Can you verify the plug-in version? If it still does not work, can you provide some more detail on what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but first you must install the `Python plug-in`  in version intellij ultimate **12.1.7**, follow through with creating a new project and you'll see the `django technology`

**installation**

> > > > File > Settings > Plugins > Install JetBrains plugin... > Python

After installation, create a new project using `Python Module`

> > > > create a project name > next > next > select DJANGO